# biblatex: Adding Entry-Specific Information to Bibliography (Journal Ratings)

Tags: biblatex, apa-style

for a paper I need to add Journal Ratings to the entries in my bibliography.
I tried to do so by using:

```
\begin{filecontents}{biblatex-dm.cfg}
\DeclareDatamodelFields[type=field,datatype=literal]{rating}
\DeclareDatamodelEntryfields{rating}
\end{filecontents}

\DeclareFieldFormat{rating}{#1}
\renewbibmacro{finentry}{\finentry\par\printfield{rating}}
```

Now, this didn't work. I added a "rating" field into my bib file but nothing changed... so I guess this is not the correct way to add something to your bibliography.

I'm currently using the following package:

```
\usepackage[style=apa, backend=biber]{biblatex}
\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc,title={Literaturverzeichnis}]
```

Answer (score 3):

Seems to work (next time post actual code which demonstrates your issue):

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{biblatex-dm.cfg}
\DeclareDatamodelFields[type=field,datatype=literal]{rating}
\DeclareDatamodelEntryfields{rating}
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{\jobname.bib}
@article{testa,
  author = {Author, An},
  title = {Title A},
  journaltitle = {Journal Name},
  volume = {1},
  date = {2022},
  rating = {3}
}
@article{testb,
  author = {Author, Another},
  title = {Title B},
  journaltitle = {Difference Journal Name},
  volume = {5},
  date = {2020},
  rating = {4}
}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage{fontawesome}
\usepackage[style=apa]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\newcount\rating
\newcount\ratingmax
\newcount\ratingiter
\ratingmax5
\DeclareFieldFormat{rating}{%
  \rating#1
  \ifnum\rating<0\rating0\fi
  \ifnum\rating>\ratingmax\rating\ratingmax\fi
  \ratingiter0
  \loop\ifnum\ratingiter<\rating
    \faStar
    \advance\ratingiter1\relax
  \repeat
  \loop\ifnum\ratingiter<\ratingmax\relax
    \faStarO
    \advance\ratingiter1\relax
  \repeat
}
\renewbibmacro*{finentry}{\finentry\par\printfield{rating}}
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: +1 Very cool-looking solution!